swap mechanism - linked list
I would have thought this is the same thing but it's not
This is not working
cur, cur.next, prev = cur.next, prev, cur

This is working
cur.next, cur, prev = prev, cur.next, cur

on several lines:
tmp = cur.next
cur.next = prev
prev = cur
cur = tmp

I am trying to understand the internal mechanism of python

When evaluating an assignment <target(s)> = <expression>, the expression is evaluated in its entirety before the result is assigned to the target(s).
Evaluations of expressions typically happen in a deterministic fashion, and for a tuple expression like <x>, <y>, ..., this is from left to right.
So, for:
cur, cur.next, prev = cur.next, prev, cur 

cur.next, prev, cur is evaluated and results in a tuple of three values: whatever cur.next is, then prev, then cur.
This 3-tuple of values (which won't change during the assignment) is then unpacked over the targets and assignment happens sequentially (left to right). So, cur gets assigned cur.next, then cur.next (this is the .next of the new cur) gets assigned prev, and finally prev gets assigned cur - however it's important to realise this is still the cur value as was evaluated, not the changed cur.
Similarly, for:
cur.next, cur, prev = prev, cur.next, cur 

prev, cur.next, cur is evaluated and results in a tuple of three values: whatever prev is, then cur.next, then cur.
This 3-tuple of values is then unpacked over the targets and assignment happens sequentially. So, cur.next gets assigned prev, then cur gets assigned cur.next (the previous value, not the new prev value), and finally prev gets assigned cur - again this is still the cur value as was evaluated, not the changed cur.
So, the result is different. cur still becomes cur.next, but cur.next gets the value of prev instead of cur.next.next getting that value. This also means that, if cur.next was initially None, the 2nd assignment won't throw an exception, while the 1st one will.
Another way of looking at this:
x, y, z = a, b, c

Is like this (which is equivalent):
k = a
l = b
m = c

x = k
y = l
z = m

For your problematic example, this works out to:
k = cur.next  # cur.next can be None here, thus k will be None
l = prev
m = cur

cur = k
cur.next = l  # what if k was None? this will throw an exception
prev = m

Also consider this example:
class Link:
    def __init__(self, data, next_=None):
        self.data = data
        self.next = next_


def main():
    elem = Link(0)
    root = Link(1, elem)

    print(root.data, root.next.data)

    cur, cur.data = root, 2  # cur.data can be assigned here, after cur
    cur, cur.data = cur.next, cur.data  # cur is updated before cur.data

    print(root.data, root.next.data)


main()

The output is
1 0
2 2

Where some might expect an error on the first assignment, or for the result to be 2 0.
Generally, you would do well to avoid these types of constructions in this scenario. This is a good example where shorter code is not better code. It's hard to interpret, easy to misunderstand, and hardly any faster - if at all. Tuple unpacking is a useful feature and can be very pythonic, but don't use it where it makes things harder to understand and maintain.

ok but the first options (cur, cur.next, prev = cur.next, prev, cur)  gives me the following error
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'next'
this works:
cur.next, cur, prev = prev, cur.next, cur
so it must be something else

No, if you read carefully, the first option tries to effectively assign prev to cur.next.next. At the time, the cur.next value assigned to cur is apparently None (we can't tell) and referring to cur.next would then result in that error. I've updated the answer with a specific example to make that even more clear.

you are right, so morning, everything is clear. sorry.

You're welcome - if you feel the answer answers your question, consider clicking the checkmark to accept it, so your question no longer appears as unanswered. If you do need further help, feel free to ask.
